# Mounting USB Stick As Internal Storage On Raspberry Pi

Tags: usb, storage

I am thinking about setting up a media Center with a raspberry pi... The only downside is, I am thinking about running Debian and OSMC and I wouldn't have much space left to use. So is it possible to mount a USB stick as an internal storage device?

Sid

Comment: There seems to be a minor misconception here - but what do you mean by "internal storage"? The Pi is perfectly capable of mounting a number of external storage devices such as USB sticks or HDD enclosures.

Comment: My raspberry pi has a 8 gb SD card - it says it has 8gb internal storage, if I have a 16gb USB, mount it, will it sat I have 24gb?

Comment: Once mounted there be little enough difference whatever OSMC calls it. It will be possible to configure a suitable mount point that OSMC will be able to use for media files.

Comment: Duplicated question : http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/12404/booting-from-an-external-usb-drive

Comment: No, I am not asking how to boot from an SD card

Comment: The simplest solution would be to get at least 16GB SD card, as OSMC developers suggest.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I think that'll be a more simple solution